# Como reiniciar as configurações do OpenFire?

Tags: lado-do-servidor, openfire, xmpp, configuração

Estou trabalhando com um projeto que usa um servidor XMPP. Estou usando o OpenFire para montar um ambiente de desenvolvimento e teste. Depois de iniciá-lo pela primeira vez ele oferece um passo a passo para configurá-lo. Acho que errei alguma coisa na configuração e gostaria de refazer o passo a passo incial, mas mesmo parando e reiniciando sou sempre redirecionado para a tela de login.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei qual o seu sistema operacional, mas na pasta do openfire tem um arquivo `openfire.xml` dentro de `conf`.

Nesse arquivo troca `<setup>true</setup>` para `<setup>false</setup>`

Reinicia o servidor, e vai ver novamente o passo a passo.